# How can I extract a specific part of an input?

Tags: python, class, extract, user-input

First of all I am making some sort of timer (you'll know why I say this). I have a class and each parameter takes an integer as input. Now, whenever I ask the user to input a value (for example, they could input "3hrs 2mins 1s") I want to get the numbers; but that's not the matter. The matter is that idk how I could get rid of those words, like getting rid of "hrs" so I can just take the number (eventually I would have to convert it into a int). Any ideas? Hope I was clear.

Comment: Try [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or use regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match the numbers only. Using `re.findall()` you can get a list of results that match the given regular expression.

```
import re

user_input = '11hrs 2mins 1s'           # You can use `input()`
time = re.findall('\d+', user_input)    # Find all results
time = [int(i) for i in time]           # Convert each of the numbers to digits

print(time)
```

Here, `\d` means any digit and `+` means occurring more than once. Thus using `findall()` function you get a list of numbers captured within the string.

#### Output

---

```
[11, 2, 1]
```